# Firebase startat timestamp issue?

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have an issue with firebase. I'm trying to start at specific timestamp, but it seems like it's not starting at the specified timestamp. In the log you can see the variable `this.state.timeAtMount` is greater than the `date_add` child.

```
    ref
          .orderByChild('date_add')
          .startAt(this.state.timeAtMount)
          .on('child_added', snapshot => {


            console.log('TIME MOUNT', this.state.timeAtMount);
            console.log('ANSWERS TO REPLY child_added', snapshot);
})
```

THE LOG :

```
TIME MOUNT 1574536646740
ANSWERS TO REPLY child_added Object {
  "author": "MJE3PrCYJXT4yv2LHF9S229CLRA2",
  "date_add": 1574535388800,
  "question": "S",
}
TIME MOUNT 1574536646740
ANSWERS TO REPLY child_added Object {
  "author": "MJE3PrCYJXT4yv2LHF9S229CLRA2",
  "date_add": 1574535448836,
  "question": "Sss",
}
TIME MOUNT 1574536646740
ANSWERS TO REPLY child_added Object {
  "author": "MJE3PrCYJXT4yv2LHF9S229CLRA2",
  "date_add": 1574536634684,
  "question": "S",
}
```

Comment: Interesting. At first glance I don't see what that is happening. Can you set up a repro on a site like jsbin, so that I can take a live look?

Comment: I presume there's nothing that is changing `this.state.timeAtMount` between when the query is set up and when the callbacks are happening?

Comment: i just changed this.state.timeAtMount with date.now() directly and it's working weird